# What's the right way to use Bower in ASP.Net 5 and VS2015?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, bower, visual-studio-2015

I currently try to get myself into ASP.Net 5 development, and I'm struggling to find the "way to go" for using **Bower** in this.

My project structure looks more or less like this:

```
testProject
  - wwwroot
      - index.html
  - bower_components (hidden by default in project.json)
      - angular
          - ...
      - ...
  - node_components  (hidden by default in project.json)
      - grunt
          - ...
      - ...
  - bower.json
  - Gruntfile.js
  - package.json
  - project.json
  - Startup.cs
```

I can't access `bower_components` in `index.html` and as it's not included in the project by default I guess it's meant this way.

So what's the expected way to work with the bower libraries?

I've seen many people are using `grunt-bower-task` to install the libraries once again into `wwwroot/lib` (or some other folder in the wwwroot), but this seems kind of redundant to me as Visual Studio already installs the packages into the project directory.

An alternative would be to use use `grunt-copy` to move the files from `bower_components` into the target folder, but with this way you would have to list every library you want to include once again.

So has anyone already gained some experience with this handling and would share how you are doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmmm.. Didn't sure I understand the problem right, but anyway, if the problem just in bower destination folder, just add `.bowerrc` file to your root with content like:

```
{
    "directory" : "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

and after `bower install` command, bower will download libs in your dest folder

Comment: but why isn't this the default handling of VS2015? Why is the bower_components folder in the root directory and excluded by default?

Comment: @Staeff I didn't know why. Bower targets to the `root/ bower_components` fiolder by default (it's not because VS). But why it excluded I didn't know.

Comment: I believe it first downloads components into the bower_components folder to use as the local truth-source. Then you may selectively add specific files from that source to your wwwroot/lib. For example, you might download via bower a suite of js libraries, but only require 1 for your project. This is similar to what NuGet does - downloading all files of a component into its packages/xyz folder, and you can selectively include references to the parts you need.